# How to set feature policy headers in JS

Tags: javascript, policy

I am getting the following errors in my console on my site:

```
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'unsized-media'.
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ambient-light-sensor'.
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'speaker'.
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'vr'.
```

I am a front end web developer so I'm trying to set this in JS as described here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/feature-policy#js without messing with my server config.

```
console.log(document.featurePolicy.allowedFeatures());
```

results in:

```
["geolocation", "midi", "ch-ect", "usb", "magnetometer", "picture-in-picture", "publickey-credentials-get", "accelerometer", "ch-lang", "document-domain", "encrypted-media", "ch-downlink", "ch-ua-arch", "xr-spatial-tracking", "ch-ua-platform-version", "ch-width", "ch-ua-model", "sync-xhr", "camera", "ch-viewport-width", "payment", "ch-rtt", "ch-ua-full-version", "fullscreen", "autoplay", "ch-dpr", "ch-ua-platform", "screen-wake-lock", "gyroscope", "ch-ua-mobile", "ch-device-memory", "ch-ua", "microphone"]
```

Also

```
document.featurePolicy.allowsFeature('unsized-media', 'self');
```

results in:

```
Invalid origin url for feature 'unsized-media': self.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't.

Feature policies are set by the server (via the `Feature-Policy` or `Permissions-Policy`  headers) and control what JavaScript is allowed to do.

It would be pointless if the JavaScript could grant itself permission to do anything it liked.

Comment: I was just going by that Google article, how would I go about setting these on the server though, I've found some documentation and tried editing the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and added `Header always set Feature-Policy "unsized-media 'self'"` but that just duplicated the unsized-media error

Comment: @PaddyHallihan — If a browser doesn't support a feature, you can't add support for it from your website. There's no way, for instance, for an HTTP header to add a VR headset to the user's system or add APIs to the browser so that your JavaScript can access one that the hardware has but the browser doesn't understand.

Comment: Why are these errors only appearing on specific pages on my site though and how can I get rid of the errors

Comment: For me, they appear on every page I show a youtube video.